# Does AWS Amazon Certificate Manager Generate Client certificates for Customer (3rd Party Clients)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Could you kindly help me out with an answer.

Does AWS Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM CA) (or maybe LetsEncrypt) generate Client certificates for Customer (3rd Party Clients), i.e. the client certificates will be deployed on my third-party customers' laptops? They are staff of third-party organisations; and I need to do mutual client certificate-based TLS/SSL authentication between their laptop/PC browsers and my web-site or service, which will be AWS-hosted.

If so are are there any associated costs or limitations. Next are there any AWS, LetsEncrypt or other tools to support the Certificate deployment, key rotation on Certificate Expiry, etc.

Thanks,
JoeBoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it using let's encrypt while with AWS cert-manager it is also possible. if you have generated certificate locally you can also manually upload it to AWS cert manager.

for more info you can check this out : https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificate-for-a-third-party-web-host-using-csr/76805/8

Comment: if answer solved mark it as answer as up vote. else i can help more if needed